# JSHint error: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

Tags: javascript, jshint

When I use JSHint here I get an error. How to deal with it?

My js:

```
//completed

typeof(onloadedcompleted) == 'function' && onloadedcompleted(NUM_ELEMENTS, NUM_LOADED, NUM_ERROR);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1**

Use an `if` statement instead of the `&&` operator (this is what I would do):

```
if (typeof(onloadedcompleted) == 'function') {
    onloadedcompleted(NUM_ELEMENTS, NUM_LOADED, NUM_ERROR);
}
```

**Solution 2**

In your JSHint options, set `expr: true`

For more info, see here: http://jshint.com/docs/options/#expr

**Solution 3**

Tell JSHint to ignore the line:

```
typeof(onloadedcompleted) == 'function' && onloadedcompleted(NUM_ELEMENTS, NUM_LOADED, NUM_ERROR); // jshint ignore: line
```